# Dell R610 memory configuration for all 12 slots

Tags: memory, dell, dell-poweredge, configuration

I purchased 12 sticks of RAM on eBay to go into a Dell R610 server.  The RAM is ECC REG PC3-12800 DDR3-1600 yet when I occupy all 12 slots with this ram I get the following error on boot:

MEMORY Initialization Warning: Memory Size May be Reduced
MEMBIST failure – The following DIMM has been disabled by Bios: DIMM B2
MEMBIST failure – The following DIMM has been disabled by Bios: DIMM B5

I am using all of the latest versions, BIOS, etc.  I am using 2 x x5660 processors.

What is causing this issue and is it correctable?

If this RAM is incorrect what is correct to maximize the RAM on this server?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm using UEFI if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried moving the DIMM in slots B2 and B5 to see if the error message follows the DIMM?

Comment: Yes, I moved memory around, even pulled it and used memory from another R610 server which has the identical error with all 12 slots filled with the identical dual ranked 16 GB sticks.

Comment: Did the error message move with the DIMM?

Comment: No, we think the motherboard is bad, replacing tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was a combination of 1 bad memory module and a bad cpu socket (damaged pin). We replaced the motherboard today, pulled the bad memory, all is fine.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well that sucks